# Projeto Maven com Hibernate e Glassfish não gera o banco de dados

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, jpa, maven, glassfish

Tenho um projeto Maven e estou tendo problemas no momento de gerar o Banco de dados, estou utilizando o Hibernate e Glassfish 4.

Não é gerado nenhum erro, simplesmente não é gerado o bando de dados, sou novo com Maven talvez eu esteja esquecendo de alguma configuração adicional, mas não faço ideia do que seja, abaixo estão meus arquivos de configuração e o log do Glassfish ao iniciar:

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.financeiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>Financeiro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Propiedades do Projeto -->

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Dependências do Projeto -->

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Núcleo do Hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Implementação de EntityManager da JPA -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Driver JDBC do MySQL -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Financeiro">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Pessoa.class**

```
package com.financeiro.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PESSOA")
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NOME", length = 80, nullable = false)
    private long nome;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public long getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setNome(long nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

**Glassfish log:**

```
2015-03-10T09:12:17.929-0300|Informações: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
2015-03-10T09:12:17.932-0300|Informações: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2015-03-10T09:12:18.406-0300|Informações: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-03-10T09:12:18.408-0300|Informações: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-03-10T09:12:18.423-0300|Informações: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2015-03-10T09:12:18.523-0300|Informações: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2015-03-10T09:12:18.665-0300|Informações: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2015-03-10T09:12:18.779-0300|Informações: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 37ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
2015-03-10T09:12:18.831-0300|Informações: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
2015-03-10T09:12:18.870-0300|Informações: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
2015-03-10T09:12:18.968-0300|Informações: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
2015-03-10T09:12:21.355-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:22.348-0300|Informações: Java security manager is disabled.
2015-03-10T09:12:22.348-0300|Informações: Entering Security Startup Service.
2015-03-10T09:12:22.353-0300|Informações: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
2015-03-10T09:12:22.412-0300|Informações: Security Service(s) started successfully.
2015-03-10T09:12:22.801-0300|Informações: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2015-03-10T09:12:22.817-0300|Informações: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2015-03-10T09:12:22.825-0300|Informações: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2015-03-10T09:12:22.870-0300|Informações: Created virtual server server
2015-03-10T09:12:22.874-0300|Informações: Created virtual server __asadmin
2015-03-10T09:12:23.278-0300|Informações: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
2015-03-10T09:12:23.280-0300|Informações: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
2015-03-10T09:12:24.137-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.235-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.238-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.241-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.244-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.247-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.249-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.252-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.255-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.258-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.261-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.264-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.267-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.270-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.273-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:24.487-0300|Advertência: The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
2015-03-10T09:12:24.678-0300|Informações: Loading application [Financeiro] at [/Financeiro]
2015-03-10T09:12:24.681-0300|Informações: Loading application Financeiro done in 6.164 ms
2015-03-10T09:12:24.687-0300|Informações: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (3.730ms), startup services(6.923ms), total(10.653ms)
2015-03-10T09:12:24.844-0300|Informações: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
2015-03-10T09:12:24.936-0300|Informações: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
2015-03-10T09:12:25.722-0300|Informações: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://pereira:8686/jndi/rmi://pereira:8686/jmxrmi
2015-03-10T09:12:28.197-0300|Informações: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.10.4 2014-08-08 15:09:00...
2015-03-10T09:12:29.040-0300|Informações: Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
2015-03-10T09:12:29.313-0300|Informações: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@e392108 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@6b9c9961.
2015-03-10T09:12:29.754-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:30.298-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:30.316-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:30.318-0300|Informações: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-10T09:12:32.397-0300|Informações: Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) para o contexto ''
2015-03-10T09:12:33.951-0300|Informações: Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
2015-03-10T09:12:33.953-0300|Informações: Loading application __admingui done in 4.640 ms
```

***OBS:*** No glassfish foi configurado corretamente a connection pool

Comment: Fabio, sua aplicação não está gerando nenhum log ou você pegou o log incorreto. Eu desconfio que o JPA nem chegou a inicializar o contexto. Verifique se o log da aplicação está corretamente configurado e se o log está sendo gravado em outro arquivo. Se conseguir essas informações, edite sua pergunta com os dados para que possamos analisar o problema. Abraço!

Comment: Ok assim que possível vejo isso com mais cautela e posto aqui

Comment: Olha eu versifiquei todos os arquivos de log gerados pelo glassfish no entendo todos são iguais ao postado, não está havendo a inicialização do Hibernate, eu não faço ideia do que pode estar ocasionando isto é a primeira vez que trabalho com Maven eu sempre utilizei o Dynamic Web Project e a forma com a qual configurei sempre funcionou. Teria alguma coisa que deveria tentar ?

Comment: Então não deve ter o log da aplicação. Configure um arquivo `log4.xml` na sua aplicação para que ela gere os logs corretamente. Neste momento, use o nível de log DEBUG para facilitar a investigação do problema. A documentação sobre como configurar o Log4j esta no link: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: @1fabiopereira, já resolveu o problema da pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Use a propriedade

```
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

ao invés de

```
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, seu arquivo persistence.xml não tem o tipo de transação que sua aplicação utilizará (resource local ou data source), a declaração de suas classes entidades e as propriedades do banco que vc está usando, por isso não cria a base de dados. Como vc disse que usa

Exemplo:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="exemploPU" > 
    <jta-data-source>java:/BancoDataSources</jta-data-source> <!--configuração do datasource e conction pool -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>br.com.controle.model.Pessoa</class> <!-- Entity -->

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```